# Prove the following sobolev inequality

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let f be a fubction on $[0,1]$ that is continuous and has a continuous derivative f'. show that:
$\sup_{0 \leq x,y \leq 1}|f(x)-f(y)|\leq ||f'||_2$.

Do not know where to start. Any hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I have tried in that direction but did not know how to get around the l2 norm. That was the first thing that i thought about besides bounded variation related theorems

Comment: Did you use the Holder inequality?

Comment: $\|f'g\|_r\leq \|f'\|_p\|g\|_q$, take p=q=2 and g=1 which will work since you are integrating in a finite  space ($r=1$ of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|f'g\|_1\leq \|f'\|_2\|g\|_2$
for g=1 ( lebesgue integrable in [0,1]) , you end up with :

$\|f'\|_1\leq \|f'\|_2$
but

Assuming that $x\leq y$ w.l.o,g

$\sup_{0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1} \int_x^y |f'|dm \leq \int_0^1 |f'|dm $ (by monotonicity).

and $\sup_{0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1} |\int_x^y f'dm| \leq \sup_{0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1} \int_x^y |f'|dm$

and finally by applying the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$\sup_{0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1} |\int_x^y f'dm|=\sup_{0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1}|f(y)-f(x)|$

and your inequality follows immediately.